# C# - Read Paragraph From Rich Text Box

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

How do I read a paragraph from rich text box in WPF and display it in a Message Box?

Comment: TextRange textRange = new TextRange(canvas.Document.ContentStart, canvas.Document.ContentEnd);
            MessageBox.Show(textRange.Text); But it gives me all the text in the box

Comment: Put that in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to iterate through all the paragraphs in a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then the following static classes containing [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) provide the necessary methods:

```
public static class FlowDocumentExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Paragraph> Paragraphs(this FlowDocument doc)
    {
        return doc.Descendants().OfType<Paragraph>();
    }
}

public static class DependencyObjectExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendants(this DependencyObject root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            yield break;
        yield return root;
        foreach (var child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(root).OfType<DependencyObject>())
            foreach (var descendent in child.Descendants())
                yield return descendent;
    }
}
```

Once you have collected all the paragraphs in a `FlowDocument`, to convert a single paragraph to text, you can do:

```
var text = new TextRange(paragraph.ContentStart, paragraph.ContentEnd).Text;
```

And example of how to put these together is:

```
    foreach (var paragraph in canvas.Document.Paragraphs())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(new TextRange(paragraph.ContentStart, paragraph.ContentEnd).Text);
    }
```

Is that what you want?

**Update**

If for whatever reason you are uncomfortable using extension methods, you could always use traditional c# 2.0 static methods:

```
public static class FlowDocumentExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Paragraph> Paragraphs(FlowDocument doc)
    {
        return DependencyObjectExtensions.Descendants(doc).OfType<Paragraph>();
    }
}

public static class DependencyObjectExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendants(DependencyObject root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            yield break;
        yield return root;
        foreach (var child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(root).OfType<DependencyObject>())
            foreach (var descendent in child.Descendants())
                yield return descendent;
    }
}
```

And

```
    foreach (var paragraph in FlowDocumentExtensions.Paragraphs(mainRTB.Document))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(new TextRange(paragraph.ContentStart, paragraph.ContentEnd).Text);
    }
```

Comment: Ok. Let me check and I will tell you.

Comment: How do I go about with this code. FlowDocument does not contain a definition for Descendants.

Comment: @GunJack - The `DependencyObjectExtensions` static class adds an [`extension method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) named `Descendants()` to `DependencyObject` and all its subclasses, including `FlowDocument`.  Did you include both extension classes shown in my answer?

Comment: yep.. sorry for the query but am I missing a directive or keyword in declaration

Comment: @GunJack - did you include the `this` in the declaration of `public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendants(this DependencyObject root)`?

Comment: Where should I place the these class declarations?? In main window class?

Comment: @GunJack - in separate files in the same project as your main window.  Or, if you don't know how to have multiple files in a project, you could take the methods from the **update** and add them to your main window class, and call them without the class name.